# Trying to queue build in TFS server - Calling a target in TFSBuild.Proj

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

I have been using a msbuild file that builds and packages my solution to 'Client' and 'Server'. So far I have been using the below cmd to build from VS cmd prompt:

```
   msbuild.exe MyBuildFile.proj /t:Build
```

(I have a target called 'Build' which will kick start build and do the rest).

Now, my team wants to queue builds in TFS build server. I read about TFSBuild.proj file. Should I once again write all the scripts in to TFSBuild.Proj or is there a way by which I can call my 'MyBuildFile.proj /t:Build' from TFSBuild.Proj.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Mani

Comment: Are you using TFS 2010 or 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include your existing MyBuildFile.proj in a TFS 2010 build:

1. Create a new build definition
2. In the Process page, choose the UpgradeTemplate.xaml workflow
3. Select the directory of your checked-in MSBuild.proj file of choice (**checked-in under the name TFSBuild.proj**)

There might be some subtle differences between your development system and the build server that you need to take care of, but above steps should take you 85%. Enable Diagnostic level build information verbosity (also to be set on the Process page) to troubleshoot loose ends.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please let me know where to do Step 3. You mean somewhere in the Process - Build Process Parameters ?

Comment: I improved the explanation for step 3.